# Excluding with grep

Tags: grep, sh

I have this file:

```
$cat foo
foo1
foo2
foo3
foo4
bar
```

And I would like grep to print

```
foo3
bar
```

So basically, I don't know how to exclude all the foo (with -v for example) **except** foo3.

Comment: Would you also have `foo33`, and still only like `foo3`? Since this will break most solution posted here. (inclusive mine).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done with:

```
grep -v '^foo[^3]$' foo
```

You still use the `-v` exclude flag but you only exclude `foo` entries if they're followed by a non-`3`.

However, while that will work for your given input file, you may also want to strip out lines with *just* `foo` on them as well. If that's needed, use:

```
grep -v '^foo[^3]$' foo | grep -v '^foo$'
```

or:

```
grep -Ev '^foo[^3]|foo$' foo
```

If you requirements become more complex, it may be better opting for a more advanced tool. For example, the `grep` above will also give you `foo39`. For a case where the *only* `foo` lines you want are `foo3` and `foo4`, and you also want all non-`foo` lines, you can use `awk`:

```
awk '/^foo[34]$/||!/^foo/{print}' foo
```

Comment: Thanks. Now i am trying to exclude every foo **except** 'foo3' and 'foo4' witout usig '|' and a new grep.

Comment: @uuuuv: `grep -v '^foo[^34]$' foo`, but that probably should have been a different question :-) The problem in asking in a comment is that you generally get much less exposure.

Comment: And if instead of 'foo4' I had got 'foo48' and 'foo9' to exclude. Since '[^34], isn't interpreted as '34'.

Comment: @uuuuv: I often find that, if the requirements become more complex, it's sometimes better to shift to a different tool. Most people think, because tool X can do simple Y, it should also be able to do complex Y - that's not always a good assumption. In other words, think about using `awk/perl` for the added power.

Comment: If numbers get larger this will print `foo33`, `foo34` etc.  Should only print `foo3`.  OP is not clear if this may be the case.

Comment: @Jotne: yes, it will do as you say. I've already mentioned to OP that a more advanced tool may be better, so I'll add an `awk` variant that fixes that problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep -v 'foo[^3]'`, it will do a negative search.

Answer (score 0):

You can also take the direct approach:

```
grep "foo3\|bar"   # which is grep for foo3 or bar (must be double-quoted)
```

Comment: That'll work for the specific input, but won't if you have a line like `baz`.

Comment: And this is the request: `I don't know how to exclude all the foo (with -v for example) except foo3.`

Comment: And just how do you read 'for example'. Do you read that to mean 'exclusive approach sought' or in the grammatically correct context of 'one approach to take'? Or do you not even know the difference?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk` you can use:

```
awk '!/foo[^3]/' file
foo3
bar
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below grep command which uses negative lookahead,

```
$ grep -vP '^(?!foo3)foo.*$' file
foo3
bar
```

It matches all the `foo` strings except the string `foo3` string. Inverting the match by `-v` parameter will give you the desired output.